# Automatically install programs to vm

Tags: automation, virtual-machine, vsphere

I've got a question about VMs and installing programs.
I've got a vsphere 6.0 running on my server and I try to automatically create new VMs (or use clean installed snapshots) an then automatically install software on these VMs.

e.g.:
A user wishes to create a new Windows 7 with xampp installed and firefox + thunderbird + eclipse. The VM will be created and during the first start these programs will be installed.

Is this possible or are there any tools that can help?
Or can I use the VMware API to realize this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way that Vsphere can do these installations that I know of. In fact I don't know of a way to install an application to a running windows box remotely - you can imagine the security implications of that.

There is an easy way to do this however.

I would build my windows VM, install all the required applications (leaving them as configured or not depending on your needs) then convert the VM into a template and then deploy new vms based on that template. Then you have your windows vms ready to go with the installed applications.